# Excel VBA будет ли работать на iPad

Tags: ios, vba

Имеется задачка. Например: отправить письмо из Excel при помощи VBA. Будет ли VBA вообще работать на iPad и если да, то как узнать, какие ограничения накладываются на код?

Comment: Стандартные приложения для Excel не поддерживают VBA. Не знаю, насчёт сторонних приложений. В принципе, приложения со встроенными языками могут быть, к примеру, [Editorial for iOS](http://omz-software.com/editorial/) текстовый редактор позволяет на Питоне писать (я на Pythonista for iOS посылал почту  программно).

Comment: А так же есть винда и в ней все для решения задачи есть. Задача отправить письмо из таблицы Excel а не решить эту здачу сторонними языками программирования и программами.

Comment: Ваш вопрос об iOS, а не Windows. Если других приложений нельзя использовать, то можете закончить читать мой предыдущий комментарий на первом предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Если загрузить excel файл в iPad, VBA работать не будет. Есть 2 приближенных варианта:
1 - сделать макрос на JavaScript. Но его нужно хостить на сервере, в саму книгу его не поместишь. Такой макрос будет работать и через браузер на iPad.
2 - Хостить его на Sharepoint сервере, и смотреть его через браузер на iPad.